# Stop an element moving with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on a component and keep hitting an annoying bug. I have a div which when clicked on, opens up a menu. This is contained in a react component which is in turn contained in another one.

Here's the CSS:

```js
const FilterBox = styled("div")`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: ${colours.silver};
  border: 1px solid ${colours.silver};
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4px;
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

const FilterMenu = styled("div")`
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  top: 13%;
  right: 13vw;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #dddee3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: ${(props) => (props.visible ? "block" : "none")};

  label {
    display: block;
    width: 10vw;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  span {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: ${colours.night};
    input {
      margin-right: 8px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #0f7070;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 2px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      :checked {
        background-color: ${colours.green};
        :after {
          content: "\2714";
          font-size: 14px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          left: 3px;
          color: white;
          z-index: 9999;
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

For example:

[image: menu div]

[image: menu expanded]

It displays the menu etc, but the layout is messed up and I also don't think it will be at all responsive. Where am I going wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-platform-zjg8m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you put together a JSFiddle or something similar so we can see the component being used?

Comment: Sure, have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your HTML is important.

First, move the `FilterBox` element to the top of the `FilterMenu`:

```
<FilterMenu visible>
   <FilterBox
     id="filterbox"
     onClick={() => setFilterToggled(!isFilterToggled)}
    />

   {isFilterToggled &&
     allColumns.map((column) => (
       <div key={column.id}>
         <label>
           <span>
             <input type="checkbox" {...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} />{" "}
             {column.Header}
           </span>
         </label>
       </div>
     ))}
 </FilterMenu>
```

Then add `margin-left: auto` to the `FilterBox`. Your styles would then be:

```
const FilterBox = styled("div")`
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4px;
    text-align: center;
  }
`;
```

That should keep the element in the top-right corner at all times.

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-mountain-0rv2d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that <_<